# Scroll a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, richtextbox

I would like to control a *RichTextBox* scrolling but can't find any method to perform this in the control.

The reason to do this is that I want the mouse wheel scroll to be effective when the mouse cursor in over the *RichTextBox* control (it has no active focus :  mouse wheel event is handled by the form).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Side note: A Windows application which does this system-wide is "KatMouse". I sadly don't know how to do it on your own in your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting mousewheel over non-focused window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466702/detecting-mousewheel-over-non-focused-window)

Comment: You could set the RichTextBox as selected control when hovering with mouse over it.

Comment: The duplicate question leads to a link. I prefer King King answer giving a solution right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little simple with `win32`. Here you are:

```
//must add using System.Reflection
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter 
{
    bool hovered;
    MethodInfo wndProc;

    public Form1() 
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
       richTextBox1.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { hovered = true; };
       richTextBox1.MouseLeave += (s, e) => { hovered = false; };
       wndProc = typeof(Control).GetMethod("WndProc", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                                      BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) 
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x20a && hovered) //WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a
        {
           Message msg = Message.Create(richTextBox1.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
           wndProc.Invoke(richTextBox1, new object[] { msg });
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I use an `IMessageFilter` to catch the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message at the `application-level`. I also use `Reflection` to invoke the protected method `WndProc` to process the message `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, you can always use a `SendMessage` win32 function to send the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` to `richTextBox1` instead, but it requires a `declaration` import here. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks it works great! I just used the richTextBox1.Contains method to check if the cursor was hover.